# How to change the hard coded port to their environment names in deployement.toml?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, toml, wso2-identity-server

I am using some offset as I am running 2 nodes in one Virtual machine but looks like some port like (5672,9611,9711) are directly present so I suppose offset wont be applied to this ports and i will have to change it manually to get it work ... is their any way to optimise this so that when I apply offset it will change all the ports automatically in run time and I don't have to worry about to change it manually ?

Comment: What is the APIM version? AFAIK offset is applicable to these ports.. But you have to do some config changes - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/#step-8-configure-throttling

Comment: Basically, node 1 should point to node 2 as well when publishing throttling data, etc

Comment: version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can add the offset to every port by adding the following configuration to the deployment.toml

```
[server] 
offset = ""
```

You can refer the following documentation for more information on this
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/default-ports-of-wso2-products/

Comment: thanks @Buddhima for reply, but is this offset applied to port which are directly hard coded in the toml file (say 9099) ?

Comment: This will offset Management console ports, and LDAP server ports mainly. What is the port you need to offset? Can you provide me the hardcoded configuration?

Comment: [[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://10.73.111.180:9611","tcp://10.73.111.180:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://10.73.111.180:9711","ssl://10.73.111.180:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"